# combined 4 array together by specific order grouped by ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have bellow 4 array objects

```
var dataArray1 = [
{'ProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Main Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 
'StartMonth': 'Sep', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 
'Main'},
{'ProjectID': '002',  'Project': 'Main Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 
'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 
'Main'},
];

var dataArray2 = [
{'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Sub Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 
'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 
'Category' : 'Pahse'},
{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Sub Project 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 
'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 
'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '002', 'Project': 'Sub Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 
'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 
'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'Project': 'Sub Project 3', 'StartYear': '2024', 
'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to 
Start', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '004', 'Project': 'Sub Project 4', 'StartYear': '2024', 
'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to 
Start', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
];

var dataArray3 = [
  {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},      
  {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Milestone 2', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001','Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '002', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Milestone 2', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '004', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
];

 var dataArray4 = [
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},     
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Activity 2', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},
    {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 
'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 
'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Activity'},
];
```

i trying to archive bellow final array object

```
var dataArrayfinal = [

{'ProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Main Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 
'StartMonth': 'Sep', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 
 'Main'},
{'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Sub Project 1', 'StartYear': '2023', 
'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 
'Category' : 'Pahse'},
  {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 
'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 'Owner':'Tom' 
, 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 
 'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Oct', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 'Owner':'Tom' 
 , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},
  {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Milestone 2', 
  'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 
 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 
  'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Nov', 
   'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},
    {'ProjectID': '001', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Activity 2', 
   'StartYear': '2023', 'EndYear': '2023', 'StartMonth': 'Nov', 'EndMonth': 'Dec', 
   'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Passed', 'Category' : 'Activity'},

   {'ProjectID': '002', 'Project': 'Main Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 
   'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 
   'Main'},
   {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'Project': 'Sub Project 1', 'StartYear': 
   '2024', 
   'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001','Project': 'Milestone 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
    {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '001', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Activity 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Activity'},

{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '002', 'Project': 'Sub Project 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '002',  'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Jan', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Inprogress', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},

{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'Project': 'Sub Project 3', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Feb', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '003', 'MilestoneID': '002', 'Project': 'Milestone 2', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Feb', 'EndMonth': 'Mar', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},

{'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '004', 'Project': 'Sub Project 4', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Pahse'},
  {'ProjectID': '002', 'SubProjectID': '004', 'MilestoneID': '001', 'Project': 'Milestone 1', 'StartYear': '2024', 'EndYear': '2024', 'StartMonth': 'Mar', 'EndMonth': 'May', 'Owner':'Tom' , 'Status':'Yet to Start', 'Category' : 'Milestone'},
];
```

i have tried bellow code and managed to combined first array with second array by matching subproject ID

```
var dataArrayfinal = [];

 // Iterate over dataArray1
 for (var i = 0; i < dataArray1.length; i++) {
 dataArrayfinal.push(dataArray1[i]);

 // Find matching items in dataArray2
var matchingItems2 = dataArray2.filter(item => item.ProjectID === dataArray1[i].ProjectID);
dataArrayfinal = dataArrayfinal.concat(matchingItems2);
```

}

i was not able to move and add the milestones array and activity array group. any way to archive this ?

basically what i want is to combined my first array which contains main project details with second array which is my sub project array. then combined that with milestones array. finally with activity array. but at the same time this need to follow the order. project->subproject->milestones->activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a multi-level grouping over

- `ProjectID`,
- `SubProjectID`,
- `MilestoneID`

and take a flat array as result.

```js
const
    data1 = [{ ProjectID: "001", Project: "Main Project 1", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Sep", EndMonth: "Dec", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Main" }, { ProjectID: "002", Project: "Main Project 2", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "May", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Inprogress", Category: "Main" }],
    data2 = [{ ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", Project: "Sub Project 1", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Oct", EndMonth: "Dec", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Pahse" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "001", Project: "Sub Project 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Inprogress", Category: "Pahse" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "002", Project: "Sub Project 2", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Inprogress", Category: "Pahse" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "003", Project: "Sub Project 3", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Feb", EndMonth: "Mar", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Pahse" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "004", Project: "Sub Project 4", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Mar", EndMonth: "May", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Pahse" }],
    data3 = [{ ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Milestone 1", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Oct", EndMonth: "Nov", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "002", Project: "Milestone 2", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Nov", EndMonth: "Dec", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Milestone 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "002", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Milestone 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Inprogress", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "003", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Milestone 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Feb", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "003", MilestoneID: "002", Project: "Milestone 2", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Feb", EndMonth: "Mar", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Milestone" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "004", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Milestone 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Mar", EndMonth: "May", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Milestone" }],
    data4 = [{ ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Activity 1", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Oct", EndMonth: "Nov", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Activity" }, { ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "002", Project: "Activity 1", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Nov", EndMonth: "Nov", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Activity" }, { ProjectID: "001", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "002", Project: "Activity 2", StartYear: "2023", EndYear: "2023", StartMonth: "Nov", EndMonth: "Dec", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Passed", Category: "Activity" }, { ProjectID: "002", SubProjectID: "001", MilestoneID: "001", Project: "Activity 1", StartYear: "2024", EndYear: "2024", StartMonth: "Jan", EndMonth: "Feb", Owner: "Tom", Status: "Yet to Start", Category: "Activity" }],
    data = [...data1, ...data2, ...data3, ...data4],
    keys = ['ProjectID', 'SubProjectID', 'MilestoneID'],
    groupBy = (data, [key, ...rest]) => {
        if (key === undefined) return data;

        const
            getValue = key => object => object[key] ?? '';

        return Object
            .values(Object.groupBy(data, getValue(key)))
            .flatMap(data => groupBy(data, rest));
    },
    result = groupBy(data, keys);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```